# 'npm run build' or 'yarn run build' on node server throws 100+ module not found errors

Tags: node.js, webpack, build, node-modules

I am using webpack module to build my node server.
Following is the content under **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.txt', '.ts'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  target: 'node',
};
```

Following are the dev dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.79.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
 }
```

I tried the following:

1. installing the packages after deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json.
2. used yarn instead of npm

However, none worked.

I haven't understood the reason behind the error at the first place.
I'd appreciate if anyone would take this.